# How can I make this jquery function more terse?

Tags: jquery, livequery, jquery-lint

I have this code in a common javascript file in my asp.net project.

jQuery-Lint returns "You've used the same selector more than once" whenever I mouse over one of the buttons that was affected by this function.

```
//turns all the buttons into jqueryUI buttons
//#mainBody is on the master page, #childBody is on the modal page.
$("#mainBody button, #mainBody input:submit, #mainBody input:button, #childBody button, #childBody input:submit, #childBody input:button").livequery(function () {
    $(this).button().each(function (index) {
                            $(this).ajaxStart(function () {
                                    $.data(this, "old_button_val", $(this).val());
                                    $.data(this, "old_button_disabled", $(this).button("option", "disabled"));
                                    $(this).button("option", "disabled", true).val("Wait...");
                                }).ajaxStop(function () {
                                    $(this).val($.data(this, "old_button_val")).button("option", "disabled", $.data(this, "old_button_disabled"));
                                }).ajaxError(function () {
                                    $(this).val($.data(this, "old_button_val")).button("option", "disabled", $.data(this, "old_button_disabled"));
                                });
                        });
});
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559023/jquery-lint-says-youve-used-the-same-selector-more-than-once-i-dont-think-i).

Comment: You don't need to use `.each` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Might be a good idea now to add a class to these element
// instead of using a long selector like this
// Additionally, :button already includes <button> elements
var selector = "#mainBody input:submit, #mainBody input:button, #childBody input:submit, #childBody input:button";

$(selector).livequery(function() {
    // Store a copy of $(this), which we'll reuse... and reuse... and reuse
    var t = $(this);

    // Create the callback function shared berween
    // ajaxStop and ajaxError
    function ajaxCallback () {
        t.button('option', {
             label: t.data("old_button_val"),
             disabled: t.data('old_button_disabled')
         });
    }

    t.button()
        .ajaxStart(function() {
            // Use $.fn.data instead of $.data
            t.data({
                // Using 'label' instead of 'val'
                // because <button> elements do not have 'value's
                "old_button_val", t.button('option', 'label'),
                "old_button_disabled": t.button("option", "disabled")
            }).button('option', {
                disabled: true,
                label: 'Wait...'
            });
        }).ajaxStop(ajaxCallback).ajaxError(ajaxCallback);
    });
});
```

Disclaimer: Not tested, therefore not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Note: you must use jQuery 1.4.3 or later to pass a key/value pair object to .data! Otherwise you might see an error like "e is undefined" in this script.